# Powershell Command for retrieving the second pattern values

Tags: powershell

I am facing problem while using multiple patterns to retrieve the values from the second pattern.

The file contains data like below

> Explore/CommonServices/AlertService.Folder
>
> Explore/CommonServices/CIHLogger.Folder

What I am trying to do is find the text between two forward slashes i.e CommonServices and find the text between one forward slash and the dot i.e AlertService

I am able to find them using the patterns `'/(.+)/'` and `'/([^/]+)\.'` respectively. Now the challenge is how to get them into a single line

My Command is

```
((get-content "test2.txt") | Select-String -pattern '/(.+)/','/([^/]+)\.' -context 0,2 | foreach {"iics export --podHostName dm-us.informaticacloud
.com -r us -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxx --artifacts " + $_ + " --zipFilePath `"C:\Users\breddy002\Documents\NJR\SVN\" + $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value + "\" +  $($_.Matches[1].Groups[1].value)
})
```

I am not sure how to get the second pattern output in the second output

Powershell version is : echo `$PSVersionTable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.771
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
switch -regex -file 'text2.txt' {
    '/(?<Slash>[^/]+)/(?<Dot>[^/\.]+)\.' { 
        $Slash = $Matches.Slash
        $Dot = $Matches.Dot
        "First: {0}, Second: {1}" -f $Slash,$Dot 
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `switch` statement is a robust `if` statement. With the `-regex` and `-file` parameters, you can efficiently read in each line of a file and apply regex pattern matches. Each successful match is stored in the automatic variable `$Matches`.

The regex pattern `/(?<Slash>[^/]+)/(?<Dot>[^/\.]+)\.` matches as follows:

- `/` is a literal match of `/`
- `(?<Slash>[^/]+)` matches one or more (`+`) characters that are not `/` (`[^/]`). That match is stored as capture group `Slash` (using syntax `(?<Slash>)`). It can later be accessed by using the syntax `$Matches.Slash`.
- `(?<Dot>[^/\.]+)` matches one or more characters that are not `/` and `.` (`[^/\.]+`). That match is stored as capture group `Dot`. It can later be accessed by using the syntax `$Matches.Dot`.
- `\.` is a literal `.` match, which requires escaping with backslash.

Comment: Thank you..This was exactly what I was looking for